# Magnific Popup - taller mfp-bottom-bar causes max image height issue

Tags: magnific-popup

I am customizing the title of the Magnific popup/lightbox to include more than one row of content by using the 'change' callback, and modifying the content of

```
this.content
```

within the callback.  It is working correctly, except for the fact that if the image within the popup is very tall, or the window re-sizes to a smaller height, the calculation that Magnific is doing to adjust the 'max-height' of the image seems to only take into account a single row of text for the title.

Does anyone know what is needed to adjust the max-height calculation of the image to take into account a taller title box?

Thank you

**** Edit

A quick hack to jquery.magnific-popup.js around line 461 in the "updateSize:" callback has allowed me to get around this problem.  It seems reasonable to for this popup/lightbox to accept a max height in percentage so that it doesn't fill the screen.

Here's my change, I'd appreciate some feedback if possible.  Thanks!

```
updateSize: function(winHeight) {

    if(mfp.isIOS) {
        // fixes iOS nav bars https://github.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup/issues/2
        var zoomLevel = document.documentElement.clientWidth / window.innerWidth;
        var height = window.innerHeight * zoomLevel;
        mfp.wrap.css('height', height);
        mfp.wH = height;
    } else {
        mfp.wH = winHeight || _window.height();
        // ########################################
        // CHANGE IS RIGHT HERE TO FORCE 80% height
        // ########################################
        mfp.wH *= 0.8;
    }
    // Fixes #84: popup incorrectly positioned with position:relative on body
    if(!mfp.fixedContentPos) {
        mfp.wrap.css('height', mfp.wH);
    }

    _mfpTrigger('Resize');

},
```

Answer (score 5):

You can limit the max height of the image in the resize callback, which will allow more room for the title:

```
$('a.magnific').magnificPopup({
    type: 'image',
    callbacks: {
        resize: function() {
            var img = this.content.find('img');
            img.css('max-height', parseFloat(img.css('max-height')) * 0.95);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This one worked great for me. Although I needed to add the same callback for `resize` and `change` for it to work thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add my contribution. As I wanted to include both titles and descriptions to images. This meant that I couldn't fit all this information in the viewport space. The description was cut off and I was left with a scrollbar.

**@alexantd** - I tried your callback addition which only works when the window is being resized.

**@ajhuddy** - Your solution worked perfectly for me. I was able to fit the text in fine. Though the image was considerably small with a lot of space at the top.

I adjusted the padding as to regain 40px space to display a slightly larger image. Here's my CSS to do so. The CSS below allowed me to reduce images to 0.85 (85%).

```
.mfp-img {
  padding: 0px 0px 40px !important;
}
.mfp-close {
  margin-top: -40px;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
else b.wH=a||v.height()**,b.wH*=.9**;b.fixedContentPos
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".